# Rails Devise adds additional required sign on every page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, formtastic

Having a weird devise problem.

[image: asteriks beeing added on devise form]

**The code looks like this:**

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
    %a{ :href => "#log_in"}
      =t :log_into_your_account
  %li
    %a{ :href => "#"}
      =t :not_yet_registered

.tab-content
  .tab-pane.active#log_in
    %h2 Sign in
    = semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      = f.semantic_errors
      = f.inputs do
        = f.input :email
        = f.input :password
      -if devise_mapping.rememberable?
        .clearfix
          = f.label :remember_me
          .input
            = f.check_box :remember_me
      = f.buttons do
        = f.commit_button :button_html => {:class => "btn btn-success"}
= render :partial => "devise/shared/links"
```

Generally speaking, how would I go about diagnosing things like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the gem. Fixed now.

```
gem "formtastic", "~> 2.1.1"
```